# Enumerate Webcam Devices in Local System

Tags: windows, delphi, hardware, webcam

I'm curious if there is an example of how to enumerate all webcam devices installed on the system.
From what I have read you can use the Win32 SetupAPI calls. I'm interested in populating a listbox to determine if a device should be enabled or disabled. The only thing that I've read about to do this is to call SetupDiChangeState() but I would need to filter this device first before I could even do so, and with what criteria? I guess any help would be appreciated if someone is experienced in using such an API to enumerate physical devices for state change. Thank you in advance for anything you can explain or provide examples for.

Comment: [Discover and select camera capabilities with camera profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera-profiles). Pick whichever Delphi language projection for the Windows Runtime you prefer (assuming there are any), or access the raw ABI interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'd prefer to use SetupAPI, as I've researched. It also supports more legacy versions of Windows and not just Windows 10